# where can we find followers of purva-mimamsa in current period

Tags: vedas, purva-mimamsa

are there still any followers of poorva meemamsa.
As far As i know .. almost all hindus follow vedanta

If they are there where do they reside ?

Comment: There is one professor in Sampoornananda Sankrit Vidyalaya,